# How do online applications register ports for connection?

Tags: c#, port, tcpclient

I've been having issues with building applications that communicate online. Currently I am trying to set up a client/server app in C# using TcpClient and the usual problem with port configuration doesn't let my clients connect to the server.

Server code:

```
private static TcpListener socket;
private static int port = 16320;

public static void InitNetwork()
{
    socket = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Loopback, port);
    socket.Start();
    socket.BeginAcceptTcpClient(new AsyncCallback(ClientConnected), null);
}
```

Client code:

```
public static string ip;
public static int port = 16320;

public static TcpClient socket;
private static byte[] receiveBuffer;

public static void ConnectToServer()
{

    socket = new TcpClient
    {
        ReceiveBufferSize = 4096,
        SendBufferSize = 4096,
        NoDelay = false
    };
    receiveBuffer = new byte[socket.ReceiveBufferSize];
    socket.BeginConnect(ip, port, ConnectCallback, socket);
}
```

This works with localhost ip address but when I try to connect to my public ip I get the following error on the client:

```
System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: 'A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:16320'
```

In my system there are currently many applications that communicate online through some ports that I never had to forward.

My question is: how do applications that need to communicate online register their ports within a system so that the connections can be successful? What does an application need to do in order for this to work without the user having to log into their router and forward the corresponding port?

Edit: my question was more general but since requested I have added code.

Comment: Very vague description there. You should read about One-to-many NAT and UPnP.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the source code of the client and the source code of the server. Also explain how you run your two applications (client and server) and where you run your applications.

Comment: I have added the code responsible for client and server.

Comment: You only need to set-up port-forwarding and/or UPnP when you want to accept **incoming** TCP connections (i.e. when you want to run a _server_ of some kind). You don't need to do any of that when you're making outbound connections (i.e. when you're running a _client_ that connects to a server elsewhere).

Comment: What is the nature of your "public IP address", exactly? Is it IPv4 or IPv6? Is the _host_ computer running in your LAN NAT's DMZ or is it shielded by your firewall? What about any software/OS firewalls running on the computer? (e.g. Windows Defender Firewall).

Comment: They just don't, security software demands understanding the protocol and parks any ports it can't understand behind a firewall.  HTTP is king.

Comment: The server runs on my laptop in my private home network behind my router (IPv4) with Windows Firewall. The client tries to connect from a remote computer behind it's own firewall and router.